# I have a many to many relationship that involves invoice and products

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating a many to many-to-many relationship between the entities Invoice and Product as a hobby.
In my InvoiceProductController, I am trying to create an InvoiceProduct,but in the middle of creating of an invoiceProduct, for some reason the Product QtyOnHand did not decrease when I clicked on the create button.

I got an error when I ran the program, saying that Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have the evidence right here, in my InvoiceProductsController:

```
Product pro = db.InvoiceProducts.Find(invoiceProduct.Product).Product;
            pro.QtyOnHand -= invoiceProduct.QtyOrd;
```

After putting it after I created the InvoiceProduct, I still got the error.  It still reads object not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Either `db` or `invoiceProduct` is null, or the result of `Find()` is null.  Use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be caused by Lazy Loading?

If that's the case, the code below should work.

```
var pro = db.InvoiceProducts
             .Include("Product") //explicitly loading Product
             //for below: possibly x.Product.ID == invoiceProduct.Product.ID ?
             .Where(x=>x.Product == invoiceProduct.Product) 
             .FirstOrDefault().Product;
pro.QtyOnHand -= invoiceProduct.QtyOrd;
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() requires a parameter.

Comment: Is it asking you to pass a parameter in? I've never had to pass in a parameter in. What type of parameter is it asking for?

Comment: It's a linq query

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, FirstOrDefault() doesn't require any parameter. I think you are facing a different issue. Please see this link for FirstOrDefault(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For some reason, pro is null.  I used my debugger to locate this. I read the link and found out that firstOrdefault does not require a parameter. Here is the evidence that caused this output:

Comment: var pro = db.InvoiceProducts
             .Include("Product") //explicitly loading Product
                    //for below: possibly x.Product.ID == invoiceProduct.Product.ID ?
             .Where(x => x.Product == invoiceProduct.Product)
             .FirstOrDefault().Product;

Comment: In the .Where() clause try removing x.Prduct == invoiceProduct.Product with a more specific property. For example: x.Product.Name == invoiceProduct.Product.Name ( or use ID instead of Name, whichever property of Product you are using, make sure that it exists and has value in the InvoiceProduct.Product. )